# PouchDb in NodeJs: replication ceases after half an hour. Why?

Tags: node.js, couchdb, pouchdb

I've developed a system with CouchDB 2.2.0 as the master database, PouchDB 7.0.0 in VueJS clients and a database monitor server using PouchDB under NodeJS 8.11.1.

I can change data in CouchDB using Fauxton and the browser and mobile (PWA) clients update quickly even if left running for days.  This is NOT true of the server running PouchDB in NodeJS.  It will faithfully respond to the same changes **unless there are no changes for 20 minutes or more**, after that it simply silently ignores any and all events in CouchDB

I am setting about preparing a skeletal implementation with NodeJS and Pouch and as few other dependencies as possible and will update this question if I discover something; in the meantime I would like to ask...

Is there some well known reason why this might be happening?

How can I track down the cause without starting from scratch and gradually rebuilding the complete app brick by brick until it fails?

**Update 18-10-03**

I seem to have solved the problem by using an `fs writeStream` instead of `console.log`, without really understanding why that should make a difference.

My complete test app looks like this :

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
const adptrMemory = require('pouchdb-adapter-memory');

var stream = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/pouchLog", {flags:'a'});
const LG = (msg) => (stream.write(`${msg}
`));

const movesDB = process.env.LOCAL_DB;
LG(`Local :: ${movesDB}`);
LG(`Remote :: ${process.env.REMOTE_DB}`);

PouchDB.plugin(adptrMemory);

const movesDatabaseLocal = new PouchDB(movesDB);
const movesDatabaseRemote = new PouchDB(process.env.REMOTE_DB);


const repFromFilter = 'post_processing/by_new_inventory';
movesDatabaseLocal.replicate.from(movesDatabaseRemote, {
  live: true,
  retry: true,
  filter: repFromFilter,
})
  .on('change', (response) => {
    LG(`${movesDB} ***  NEW EXCHANGE REQUEST DELTA *** `);
    LG(`Database replication from: ${response.docs.length} records.`);
  })
  .on('active', () => {
    LG(`${movesDB} ***  NEW EXCHANGE REQUEST REPLICATION RESUMED ***`);
  })
  .on('paused', () => {
    LG(`${movesDB} ***  NEW EXCHANGE REQUEST REPLICATION ON HOLD ***`);
  })
  .on('denied', (info) => {
    LG(`${movesDB} ***  NEW EXCHANGE REQUEST REPLICATION DENIED *** ${info}`);
  })

  .on('error', err => LG(`Database error ${err}`));
```

Note that I still have not built back all the original functionality.  I can say that the failure after an idle period does occur if the above code uses `console.log`, but goes away after switching to streamed logging.

Comment: Are you using continuous replication mechanism?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but you can now see my code in my update

Comment: live:true is continuous replication

Comment: Yes.  I thought that was what you meant but I didn't wish to assume. Thanks for taking an interest.  I'm not yet 100% certain I've solved the issue, but I have a further problem with it you might have an idea about ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473019/nodejs-app-works-only-partially-under-systemd